# Module can not be found - Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I have a React project with 2 source files: `RMain.jsx` and `RCategory.jsx`. I am building the project using browserify like this:

```
gulp.task('buildDT', function(){
    browserify({
        entries: ['src/app/dataTree/RMain.jsx', 'src/app/dataTree/RCategory.jsx'],
        transform: [reactify],
        debug: true
    })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('ListApplication.js'))
        .pipe(streamify(uglify({file:'ListApplication.js'})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app/dataTree/'));
});
```

Unfortunatelly, I get the following error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Cannot find module 'RCategory.jsx'
```

The module is in the correct location. Why is this happening?

Comment: You could try switching all the relative paths to absolute paths and/or setting a `basedir` e.g. `__dirname + '/src/app/dataTree/RCategory.jsx'`

Comment: Is `RCategory` referenced somewhere in the dependency graph of `RMain`?